# How to use FTP Client with Docker containers

Tags: docker

Seemed like a fairly straightforward thing to do , I want to use an FTP client to copy files to and from a local docker container on a windows machine.

I am using a bitnami container  ( Magento 2 , but please don't tag this post as magento as it's more of a docker question )   , and I prefer using a GUI Ftp client like Filezilla as opposed to using the command line.

How can I set this up?  Or maybe I am missing something in regard to docker.

Thank you!

Comment: Is your Docker container running an FTP server?  All your container would need would be an FTP server, a user to login with and make sure to bind the port to the host.  If you just need to have files shared between the container and Windows, you should be able to use docker volumes.

Comment: get some ideas from https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=ftp&starCount=0

Comment: You can use also `docker cp` command to copy files from host to container or viceversa.

Comment: @user2915097 I think those are full containers as FTP server.

Comment: @GracefulRestart thanks , I can't see how though. seems to be different on a container - can install .. but can't start the service.. or just getting stuck.

Comment: No idea what issues you are having without further information.  Just starting the service should work if it was installed properly.  Are you sure FTP is hanging after you start it, what are you using and how are you starting it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that an FTP client opens two random ports—one for control, and one for the actual data. Because of the way that Docker networks work, you cannot dynamically map those ports. The non-secure way to resolve this is to add a flag on the run command which eliminates the network isolation of the container.

```sh
docker run [other flags] --network host <image_name>
```

Technically, this changes the network driver that the container uses.
More info on this can be found in Docker's [Networking using the host network](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/) tutorial.

Edit: Option was spelled with a single colon instead of two.